# R: How to use setdiff on two string vectors by only comparing the first 3 tab delimited items in each string?

Tags: r, string, vector, set, diff

I am trying to figure out a way in R to take the difference of two string vectors, but only based on the first 3 columns that are tab delimited in each string. For Example this is list1 and list2

list1:

```
        "1\t1113200\t1118399\t1\t1101465\t1120176\tENSRNOG00000040300\tRaet1l\t0\n" 
        "1\t1180200\t1187599\t1\t1177682\t1221416\tENSRNOG00000061316\tAABR07000121.1\t0\n"
        "1\t1180200\t1187599\t1\t1177632\t1221416\tENSRNOG00000061316\tAABR07000121.1\t0\n"
```

list2:

```
 "1\t1113200\t1118399\t1\t1101465\t1120176\tENSRNOG00000040300\tRaet1l\t0\n" 
  "1\t1180200\t1187599\t1\t1177682\t1221416\tENSRNOG00000061316\tAABR07000121.1\t0\n"
```

i want to do `setdiff(list2,list1)` , so that i just get everything in list2 that is non-existent in list1, however i want to do it based on just the first 3 tab delimited strings. So in list1 i would only consider:

```
   "1\t1113200\t1118399"
```

from the first entry. However i still want the full string returned. I only want to compare using the first 3 columns. I am having trouble figuring out how to do this, any help would be appreciated. Ive already looked at several SO posts, none of them seemed to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For extracting the first three columns (not sure why you need this as a long string rather than a dataframe...), I would use `beg2char()` from the `qdap` library. (Although, if they are all the same length base `substr()` will work fine.)

```
beg2char(list1, '\t', 3) # Will extract from the beginning up to the third tab delimiter
```

Then rather than `setdiff` I would simply use `%in%` to check if the substring of the element in `list2` matches any of the elements in `list1`.

```
beg2char(list2, '\t', 3) %in% beg2char(list1, '\t', 3) # will give you TRUE/FALSE
list2[!(beg2char(list2, '\t', 3) %in% beg2char(list1, '\t', 3))]
```

Will give the the full elements of `list2` that have substring that are nonexistent in `list1`.