# R: How to use setdiff on two string vectors by only comparing the first 3 tab delimited items in each string? without using qdap

Tags: r, tabs, set, diff, delimiter

ive previously asked this question and the answer i received worked: [R: How to use setdiff on two string vectors by only comparing the first 3 tab delimited items in each string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679578/r-how-to-use-setdiff-on-two-string-vectors-by-only-comparing-the-first-3-tab-de),
However the qdap requires rJava and correct user system setup.[cannot load R package qdap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630594/cannot-load-r-package-qdap). So now i am re-asking the question but am wondering if there is a way to do this without using qdap? i will repeat the question below:

I am trying to figure out a way in R to take the difference of two string vectors, but only based on the first 3 columns that are tab delimited in each string. For Example this is list1 and list2

list1:

```
 "1\t1113200\t1118399\t1\t1101465\t1120176\tENSRNOG00000040300\tRaet1l\t0\n" 
        "1\t1180200\t1187599\t1\t1177682\t1221416\tENSRNOG00000061316\tAABR07000121.1\t0\n"
        "1\t1180200\t1187599\t1\t1177632\t1221416\tENSRNOG00000061316\tAABR07000121.1\t0\n"
```

list2:

```
"1\t1113200\t1118399\t1\t1101465\t1120176\tENSRNOG00000040300\tRaet1l\t0\n" 
  "1\t1180200\t1187599\t1\t1177682\t1221416\tENSRNOG00000061316\tAABR07000121.1\t0\n"
```

i want to do setdiff(list2,list1) , so that i just get everything in list2 that is non-existent in list1, however i want to do it based on just the first 3 tab delimited strings. So in list1 i would only consider:

```
  "1\t1113200\t1118399"
```

from the first entry. However i still want the full string returned. I only want to compare using the first 3 columns. I am having trouble figuring out how to do this, any help would be appreciated. Ive already looked at several SO posts, none of them seemed to help.

Comment: It would be good for you to repeat the question here so we don't have to go link-hopping.

Comment: good point i will fix that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just need to extract up to the third tab character (to get the first three columns) from `list1` and compare that to the same in `list2`?

There are quite a few ways to do this in base R, here's one using regular expressions to extract the first three tabs:

```
# first, let's get the first 3 columns of `list1` (get up to the third tab)
m = regexec("^(?:[^\t]+\t){3}", list1)
# you'll see it's a list with the first 3 columns of each thing in `x`
first3.list1 = unlist(regmatches(list1, m))
```

Now we have the first three columns we can match against list2. You can extract the first three columns of `list2` similarly and use `%in%` like the answer to your previous question now. (`setdiff` will only return the non-matching first 3 columns, while using `%in%` can be used to index the original `list2` to extract the entire original string)

```
m = regexec("^(?:[^\t]+\t){3}", list2)
first3.list2 = unlist(regmatches(list2, m))
list2[!(first3.list2 %in% first3.list1)]
```

(It seems for the example you provided, there are no lines in `list2` whose first 3 columns are not in the first 3 columns of `list1`).

---

Other approaches include using `strsplit` or `read.delim` to split your dataframe into columns, then using `paste` to paste the first 3 back together, and then proceeding similarly.